# Cannot receive echo from PHP file via jQuery and AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to begin by saying sorry for asking this question because I know this has been asked a lot on here already. I've search through the site and used Google, and looked at other examples but I can't figure out what's wrong. Running the script with FireBug running shows the POST is sent but nothing gets received. I've posted the code below.

Jquery Code:

```
$('#studio').submit(function (event) {
  $('#formLaunch').click();

  $.ajax({
    url: 'test.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      search_var: 'test'
    },
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (data) {
      //$('#result').html(data);
      alert(data);
    }
  });

  event.preventDefault();
});
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$term = $_POST['search_var'];

echo $term;
?>
```

The end result of the code (once the AJAX request starts working) will process sent variables and echo an image which I want displayed in a DIV box on the page. For starters though just trying to get this basic 'shell' to work properly.

Thanks in advance for any help or direction.

Jeff

Comment: Why are you raising a click event on the '#formLaunch' element?

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(data);` to see what it's actually returning? and just to be safe - does the id="result" _really_ exist?

Comment: Seems like there are two click actions going on in one click.  Seems like you're saying "on submit, on Click, do something".  instead of having a .submit, I would just suggest using .click (on whatever button) and then using jquery .post code.  What do you think?

Comment: That's a submit event. Unless you return false or prevent the default action, the form will submit, and the page will reload, and your ajax function will not work.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that after the ajax call there is `event.preventDefault();` Also, the #formLaunch element is a hidden link that launches a modal box that #result DIV resides in. At the moment though, I've commented out the code to place the result in #result and I'm just using `alert(data);` but still no dice.

Comment: Problem solved. It was a 404 error, the path passed in the AJAX call was wrong. Should've been `scripts/test.php` Thanks for helping me through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always provide an error function, especially when in development. I suspect you have an error for a response (404, 500, etc). Providing an error function for debugging purposes will help you see this more quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It was a 404 error. I changed the path and everything works. Thanks again for everyone's input. The `console.log(data)` help me catch the error.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$.post('test.php',{'search_var': 'test'},function(data){
   alert(data);
});
```